# Extracting boundary surface of a RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, regions

Is there a way to extract boundary surface from a 3d region plot?
I've plotted my equations using:

```
kSimplified = 
  (1 + x + y + 2 x y + x^2 y + x y^2 + x^2 y^2 - z + 2 x^2 y z + 
    x^2 y^2 z - x z^2 + x^2 y z^2) /
  (y (1 + z) (1 + y + x y - z + x y z));
aSimplified = 1 + y + x y - z + x y z;
RegionPlot3D[
  kSimplified > 0 && aSimplified > 0, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0.00001, 2}, 
  {z, 0, 5}]
```

Is there any way to extract the orange part from my plot(picture below)? Or is there any smarter way to get that boundary surface?

The resulting plot is this:
[image]

Comment: Maybe with `ContourPlot3D`...

Comment: Try `ContourPlot3D[{1 + y - z + x^2 y (1 + z) (1 + y + z) + 
    x (1 + 2 y + y^2 - z^2) == 0}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0.00001, 2}, {z, 0, 
  5}, PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None]`

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!