# Extracting surface from RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, regions

As in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160813/extracting-boundary-surface-of-a-regionplot3d), I'd like to extract a surface from `RegionPlot3D`. Unfortunately, the suggestion to use `ContourPlot3D` in that question's comments doesn't work for my actual problem, which is rather involved and has a very steep gradient in the objective function.

Here's a simpler example that demonstrates the same issues as my actual problem:

```
reg = RegionPlot3D[z < (1 + 0.1 y)/(x + 10^-5), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 20}, {z, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

I'm 99% of the way there, but my solution has some artifacts.  My idea was to extract the points as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270726/):

```
pts = Flatten[Cases[Normal@reg, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity], 1];
ListPointPlot3D[pts]
```

[image]

then take the top of each stack of points:

```
top = GroupBy[pts, Part[#, 1 ;; 2] & -> Last, Max];
ListPointPlot3D[top]
```

[image]

The points look right, but when I try to get the surface with `ListPlot3D` there are weird blades I need to get rid of:

```
ListPlot3D[top, Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.5]}]
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to either remove those artifacts in `ListPlot3D`, or otherwise extract the top surface from `RegionPlot3D`?

Comment: How did you find that: "Unfortunately, the suggestion to use ContourPlot3D in that question's comments doesn't work for my actual problem"? I think it works perfectly well.

Comment: @azerbajdzan the example in my question is a simplified toy problem, because my actual problem is too complicated to post

Comment: `ImplicitRegion[And[z < (1 + 0.1 y)/(x + 10^-5), 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 20,  0 <= z <= 10 ], {x, y, z}] // BoundaryDiscretizeRegion // 
 MeshPrimitives[#, 2] &//RegionUnion` has dimension 2 as checked by `RegionDimension`. It does not look exactly like the plot in the image but maybe that is because of the scale.

Comment: I also tried to find an exact region given that you have equations using `ImplicitRegion[
 And[z < (1 + 0.1 y)/(x + 10^-5), 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 20 , 
    0 <= z <= 10] // Rationalize[#, 0] & // 
  CylindricalDecomposition[#, {x, y, z}, "Boundary"] &, {x, y, z}]` but the region is missing pieces of the original region's surface.

Comment: Hi thank you for the accept but if I may, I think that cvgmt's answer is the easiest and most robust. The answer by Michael E2 does not seem to work for constant surfaces which is why I added my second paragraph but cvgm't solution seems to always work.

Comment: @userrandrand All of your answers were very helpful, so it was hard to pick one.  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Simple case (works here)

If no mesh of the surface is ever parallel to the x,y or z plane then one can utilize the [`VertexNormals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexNormals.html) option for light shading to obtain the normals of the meshes in the x,y or z plane. These  normals look like {0,0,1}, {0,-1,0}, {0,1,0} etc but as floating point real numbers. Hence, we may  remove them like this :

(Note the usage of [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) below to convert the `GraphicsComplex` structure into an ordinary list of graphics primitives and directives to facilitate pattern matching)

(p[[2]] below has the form `VertexNormals`-> {values__} )

```
Normal@reg /. 
 p_Polygon :> 
  Nothing /; 
   AllTrue[p[[2, 2]], 
    MatchQ[Abs@Rationalize[#], {OrderlessPatternSequence[0, 1, 0]}] &]
```

[image]

That works except maybe if one explicitly changes the `VertexNormals` option via `NormalsFunction` or something.

#### More complicated scenario with piecewise constant surfaces (not the case here)

If the surface does have meshes that are parallel to the x, y or z plane then the direction of normals is not enough and one has to use the coordinates of these planes.  Such a scenario is likely rare unless one has a piece wise function or a bad mesh but for completeness a code for such a scenario is included below.

The code below takes as argument a polygon poly and a couple {n,val} where n=1,2 or 3 for x,y or z and val is the constant value taken on the plane:

```
withinPlane[couple_][poly_] := 
  AllTrue[Rationalize[poly[[1]], 
    0], #[[couple[[1]] ]] == couple[[2]] &];
```

Then one may remove the meshes belonging to planes at the boundaries of the plot:

```
Normal@reg /. 
 p_Polygon :> 
  Nothing /; 
   Or @@ Through@{withinPlane[{1, 0}], withinPlane[{1, 1}], , 
       withinPlane[{2, 0}], withinPlane[{2, 20}], withinPlane[{3, 0}],
        withinPlane[{3, 10}]}@p
```

Which leads to the same plot above.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this:

```
With[{pts = First@Cases[reg, GraphicsComplex[p_, ___] :> p, Infinity]},
 reg /. p_Polygon :> 
   Nothing /; ! 
     FreeQ[Length /@ DeleteDuplicates /@ Transpose@pts[[p[[1, 1]]]], 1]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I figured that you used `Mesh -> False` to eliminate the "jungle gym" effect. Also, adding `PlotRangePadding -> 0` seems to be an easy way to get rid of the rest of the frame, leaving just the surface floating there.

Comment: @ChrisK Actually I was in a hurry -- had to go somewhere -- and getting rid of `Mesh` seemed likely to simplify things.  You can get rid of the boundary edges with `BoundaryStyle -> None`, if that's what you meant by "frame."

Comment: Perfect, also works on my actual problem ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

- We locate the  level of the last`GraphicsGroup` and use `Delete` to delete it's upper level by `Most`.
- And `DeleteCases` the `Line`.

```
indexs = Position[reg, GraphicsGroup];
reg1 = Delete[reg, indexs // Last // Most];
DeleteCases[reg1, _Line, -1]
```

[image]

**Original**

Another possible way.

- We add `FaceForm[]` to the last `GraphicsGroup` to erase the surface and replace `Line` to `Nothing` to erase all the lines.

```
Insert[reg, FaceForm[], Position[reg, GraphicsGroup[_]] // Last] /. 
 Line -> Nothing
```

- Or `ReplacePart` the last `GraphicsGroup` to `Nothing`.

```
ReplacePart[reg, GraphicsGroup -> Nothing, 
  Position[reg, GraphicsGroup[_]] // Last] /. Line -> Nothing
```

Comment: Very nice this method even works with piecewise constant meshes like `RegionPlot3D[If[0.2 < x < 0.7 && 8 < y < 16, z < 4, z < (1 + 0.1 y)/(x + 10^-5)], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 20}, {z, 0, 10}];`

Comment: @userrandrand Thanks your example.